# Golang процесс загрузки файлов на сервер

Tags: golang, rest, vue.js, axios

В качестве http framework использую Gin

```
func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    router.Static("/", "./public")
    router.POST("/upload", controllers.Xmlparser)
    router.POST("/get_data", controllers.GetXlsxFile)
    router.Run(":8080")
}
func Xmlparser(c *gin.Context)  {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
    name := c.PostForm("name")
    email := c.PostForm("email")

    // Multipart form
    form, err := c.MultipartForm()
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("get form err: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }

    files := form.File["files"]
    for _, file := range files {
        if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, patch_load.Upload_dir.Patch + file.Filename); err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("upload file err: %s", err.Error()))
            return
        }
    }

    err = models.Xmlparser(files)
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, fmt.Sprintf("Во время загрузки произошла ошибка: %s", err.Error()))
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("Uploaded successfully %d files with fields name=%s and email=%s.", len(files), name, email))
}
```

Отправляю запрос на сервер следующим образом (vue + axios)

```
 methods: {
    uploadFiles () {
      var s = this
      const config = {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
          console.log(progressEvent)
        }}
      const data = new FormData(document.getElementById('uploadForm'))
      var imagefile = document.querySelector('#files')
      console.log(imagefile.files[0])
      data.append('file', imagefile.files[0])
      data.append('name', s.name)
      data.append('email', s.email)
      axios.post('http://192.168.1.222:8080/upload', data, config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response)
        })
    }
  }
```

Получаю такую ошибку на сервере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не пойму, как обработать OPTIONS, что бы он отдавал процесс загрузки файла.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем создавать себе головняки на ровном месте.

**OPTIONS** *используется для описания параметров соединения с ресурсом.*

**POST** *используется для отправки сущностей к определёному ресурсу. Часто вызывает изменение состояния или какие-то побочные эффекты на сервере.*

Используй то, что предусмотрено RFC2068. Следуй стандартам и все будет работать как надо.